# JButton array to int array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, int, jbutton

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe program with java swing, and I have the frame made.  How can I go about making the buttons in the JButton array activate the int array?  I want the int array to hold the values for the spots in the Tic Tac Toe grid, so when a button is pressed, the corresponding spot in the int array will be a 0 or a 1, and the text of the button will change to an X or an O.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToeGui extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    int[][] grid = new int[3][3];
    public final static int r = 3;
    public final static int c = 3;
    public final static int X = 0;
    public final static int O = 1;

    TicTacToeGui()
    {
        this.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        JButton[][] button = new JButton[3][3];
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(r, c));
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            {
                button[i][j] = new JButton("");
                button[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                panel.add(button[i][j]);
            }

        }
        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){

        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new TicTacToeGui().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own `JButton` implementation and supply an index value to.  That we you could extract it from the `ActionListener`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() instanceof MySuperButton){

        MySuperButton btn = (MySuperButton)e.getSource();
        int[] index = btn.getIndex();
        // or
        int row = btn.getRow();
        int col = btn.getColumn();

    }
}
```

Then when you set it up, you could:

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        button[i][j] = new MySuperButton(i, j); // Store the row/column
        button[i][j].addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button[i][j]);
    }

}
```

This would also allow you to store the state of the button internally...

You might also like to look at [JToggleButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

assuming the JButton indexes mirror the int array, you could search for the JButton being pressed (`e.getSource()` in `actionPerformed`) in the button array, but you have to put button array as instance variable of the class so you can use it from other methods, esp. the `actionPerformed()`. Once you find the indexes, simply update it's corresponding value in the int array.

Answer (score 0):

Use JButton's setActionCommand method to set the action command in button[0][0] to "00" and the command from button[2][1] to "21". this ill let you get the position easily right from actionPerformed. Also, you need three states, not just 2. If you're not sure what I'm talking about, play a game of tic-tac-toe and write down the array about halfway through.